# PHP: Force datatype of variable permanently

Tags: php, types, casting

I want to force a variable in PHP to be a certain datatype, so that i cannot be converted to another datatype. Example:

```
  $a = "1";
  echo "\$a has the value $a and is " . gettype($a) . "<br>\n";
  $a = $a * 2; // This should not be possible, as $a is a String and could not be used in calculations.
  echo "\$a has the value $a and now is a " . gettype($a);
```

I want to avoid that `$a` can be converted from int to String. I want to be sure that `$a` is an Integer all over my program.

Is this possible in PHP?

Comment: I suggest using C# or Java... ;-)

Comment: Exactly, I want the behavior of Java, but I have to use PHP for my project.

Comment: More seriously, see https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.declarations.php for places where you can specify types. As of PHP 8 (the current release), you still cannot do it for ordinary variables, but you can for other things such as class properties. So maybe you can find a suitable workaround. Note that these will still not throw compile-time errors like Java or C# would, they only throw runtime errors if the value isn't the correct type at the moment it's encountered. Loose typing is pretty fundamental to PHP.

Comment: If I understand you right you mean that I have to create classes (similar to wrapper-classes e.g. in Java) that handle my variables? That is what I am doing right now, but it's cumbersome.

Comment: If you want this kind of behaviour then yes. Or at least wrapper functions. Or...be careful when you write your code not to make mistakes. Or switch to using a strongly-typed language. Use the right tool for the job. If someone else mandates PHP, and you think it's that big of a deal, then make the argument as to why you should switch.

Comment: What about filtering and validating and then hydrate it into an immutable class? Suppose the number comes from a form. All values from HTML forms are transferred as strings by definition. You could filter and validate the values from the form and then hydrate them into the Immutable class. The filter will filter the type string to integer. The validator checks again whether it is really an integer value. Only when it is certain that it is an integer value is it hydrated into the immutable class. The immutable class accepts the value once and cannot be changed afterwards.